# PhoneInput value display in data preview in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, events

I'm trying to display `PhoneInput` value in a data preview (React) using an event handler `handleOnChangePhoneInput`. How do I make it work?

[Here is the source code](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-phone-input-2#events).

I want to display the "phone number" value entered by a user in the "data preview" sheet right below the "Submit" button in the demo. For example, when one enters a "first name" value and click on "Submit", the first name is displayed in the data preview but I could not make it work for "phone number" and "data of birth".

#### [Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/pedantic-field-65108)

#### Component

```
  <PhoneInput
            name="phoneNumber"
            type="text"
            country={"us"}
            enableAreaCodes={true}
            onlyCountries={["us"]}
            areaCodes={{ us: ["000"] }}
            inputProps={{
              name: "phone",
              country: "us",
              required: true,
              autoFocus: true
            }}
            value={this.state.phone}
            onChange={this.handleOnChangePhoneInput}
            inputStyle={{
              width: "230px",
              height: "45px"
            }}
          />
```

#### Event

```
  handleOnChangePhoneInput = value => {
    this.setState({ phone: value }, () => {
      return this.state.phone;
    });
  };
```

[Thanks! I'm new to React.]

Comment: The question is kinda confusing to me , could you elaborate the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this is how you would do it , First of all you need to maintain the state of your inputs so you would have to modify the state a bit

```
   state = {
        firstName: "",
        lastName: "",
        phone: "",
        emailAddress: "",
        eligibleAge: false,
        max: new Date(
          new Date().getFullYear() - 21,
          new Date().getMonth(),
          new Date().getDate()
        ),
        min: new Date(
          new Date().getFullYear() - 120,
          new Date().getMonth(),
          new Date().getDate()
        ),
        selectedDate: ""
      };
```

the next thing you want to do is create three additional event listeners one for all  the text inputs and one for the checkbox and one for the calender, this could be merged into one but for simplicity let's keep it separate

```
   // Text Inputs
    onChange = e => {
        console.log(e);
        this.setState(
          {
            ...this.state,
            [e.fieldProps.name]: e.fieldProps.value
          },
          () => {
            console.log(this.state);
          }
        );
      };
   // CheckBox
  onCheckBoxChange = e => {
    this.setState(
      {
        ...this.state,
        eligibleAge: !this.state.eligibleAge
      },
      () => {
        console.log(this.state);
      }
    );
  };
  // Calender
  onSelect = e => {
    var SelectedDate =
      e.getDate() + "-" + (e.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + e.getFullYear();
    this.setState(
      {
        ...this.state,
        selectedDate: SelectedDate
      },
      () => {
        console.log(this.state);
      }
    );
  };
```

the next thing you want to do is pass the arguments to the function.(since in the demo that you provided if a filed is empty it does not show.so i decided to mimic that by checking if that field is empty)

```
        <Form
      onSubmitStart={() =>
        this.props.onSubmitStart({
          ...(this.state.firstName !== "" && {
            firstName: this.state.firstName
          }),
          ...(this.state.lastName !== "" && {
            lastName: this.state.lastName
          }),
          ...(this.state.emailAddress !== "" && {
            emailAddress: this.state.emailAddress
          }),
          ...(this.state.phone !== "" && { phone: this.state.phone }),
          selectedDate: this.state.selectedDate,
          eligibleAge: this.state.eligibleAge
        })
      }
    >
```

and in the parent component(`index.js`) you would just change

```
handleSubmitStart = ({serialized}) => {
```

to this:

```
handleSubmitStart = serialized => {
```

**CodeSandbox** : [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/competent-bash-wx23v)

Answer (score 0):

your handle function must be something like:

```js
const handleOnChangePhoneInput = value => {
    this.setState({ phone: value });
  };
```

and then, if you want to show the value make an onClick function inside the submit button
like:

```js
const handleOnSubmit=()=>{
 this.setState({visibleTelephone:true})
}
```

and in your component you need to add where is going to show the value:

```
<div>
{this.state.visibleTelephone?this.state.phone:null}
</div>
```

Comment: @Alan you can't  display the data like `this.state.phone` .it needs to be displayed in `react-data-preview`.Plus state can be `set` perfectly fine along with the callback